# Angular - FormBuilder, how to group multiple Form Controls

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, formbuilder, formgroups

I use Formbuilder to create a FormGroup:

```
myForm = this.fb.group(
            {
                title: [""],
                fixed_grade1: [""],
                fixed_value1: [""],
                fixed_grade2: [""],
                fixed_value2: [""],
                fixed_grade3: [""],
                fixed_value3: [""],
                fixed_grade4: [""],
                fixed_value4: [""]
            });
```

all the `fixed_grade` and `fixed_value` are inputs and dropdowns.

I have 4 pairs of them, and this works correctly.

But now I would like to group these, so I don't have to access each value in my controller one by one, with `myForm.get("fixed_grade1").value` for each one.

But I would like that all these value are grouped in an array like:

```
myArray: [{grade, value}, [grade, value}...]
```

so I can access their value by: `myArray[0].grade`

Instead of mapping each single value to a new array, I saw there is a `FormArray` in `FormBuilder`, I just don't seem to be able to implement it correclty.

What would be the correct syntax to achieve what I described, having exactly 4 pairs of grade/score, and also it's important that in my final array with all these pairs grade/score, I have only the values that are not undefined, so if in my form the user only fills one pair grade/score, then my `myArray.length` will be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your `FormGroup` wrong. Your `FormGroup` should have had a `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s. Inside each of these `FormGroup`s there should have been two `FormControl`s for `grade` and `value`.

Change your form to this:

```
const grades = [
  {grade: 'Grade 1', value: 'Value 1'},
  {grade: 'Grade 2', value: 'Value 2'},
  {grade: 'Grade 3', value: 'Value 3'},
  {grade: 'Grade 4', value: 'Value 4'}
]

myForm = this.fb.group({
  title: [],
  grades: this.fb.array(this.grades.map(grade => this.fb.group({
    grade: [grade.grade],
    value: [grade.value]
  }))),
});

// OR

myForm = this.fb.group({
  title: [],
  grades: this.fb.array(this.grades.map(grade => this.fb.group({
    grade: [],
    value: []
  }))),
});
...
get gradesArray() {
  return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('grades')).controls;
}
...
getArrayGroupControlByIndex(index) {
  return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('grades'))
    .at(index);
}
```

This is how you'll use it in the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="title">
  <br>
  <div formArrayName="grades">
    <div *ngFor="let gradeGroup of gradesArray; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        Group {{ i + 1 }}
        <input type="text" formControlName="grade">
        <input type="text" formControlName="value">
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jl5goy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: ok I ll try this, I had tried doing: fixed_pairs: this.fb.array([this.createPairs()]), and then the method createPairs -> createPairs(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
   grade: ",
   score: "
  });
 }
but I was getting errors, your way seems clear enough, gonna try it and let you know

Comment: and additional question, with how my form builder was set up before, in my view I had a formControlName="fixed_value1" for each value, if I follow your way, how can I assign in my templace each of those value of the formBuilder array to an input or a dropdown?

Comment: that's it, works perfectly, exactly what I needed! One last thing, if for the single values of another field of my form Builder I was retrieving the data like this: myForm.get("title").value, and subscribing to changes with .valueChanges,  how should I access a specific value of this new form Array?  myForm.get("grades")[x].grade.value ? where x is the index of the object I want to access? Meanwhile marking your answer as corrrect one! thank you

Comment: @AJ989, just have a look at the `getArrayGroupControlByIndex` method I've just added to my answer.

Comment: yes I found that solution as well on stackoverflow thank you, trying to figure out the last thing, how to manually set a value, for the other single values I just used .get("xx").setValue,  here I'm trying to do: (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('grades'))
    .at(index).grade.setValue(x); but it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: ok nvm, found the solution for that! thank you very much all clear now

Comment: `(<FormArray>this.myForm.get('grades')).at(index).get('grade').setValue(x)`

Comment: I did it like this: (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('grades')).at(index)["controls"].grade.setValue(x, {onlySelf: true});